# Why am I seeing an error when I call requests.post multiple times in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

In this code I call requests.post() in a loop and it gives me an error

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond', None, 10060, None))
```

How can I fix this error? I searched for an answer for similar questions but they were not very similar to my problem and I did not understand

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests

URL = 'https://recruitment.aimtechnologies.co/ai-tasks'
df = pd.read_csv('dialect_dataset.csv', dtype=str)

batches = df.shape[0]//1000
size = 1000
data_id = [] 
data_tweets = []
for batch in range(batches+1):
    #print("===========================")
    ids = np.array(df['id'][size*batch:size*batch+size]).tolist()
    data_id.extend(ids)
    req = requests.post(URL, json= ids)
    data_tweets.extend(req.json().values())
```

Comment: My guess is that they are blocking you because you are flooding their site with requests.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: If that's the issue, then no -- you'll have to wait until their flood detector releases you.  Are you sure they allow batches of size 1,000?

Comment: yes. they said that the size of the list must NOT exceed 1000

Comment: I'm guessing that was intended as a healthy upper limit, not an invitation to do it exactly 1000 times.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo you mean that I should reduce the size of the batch to less than 1000?

Comment: I don't know how that limit was told to you, but if I was doing web scraping and saw a "1000 request limit" on a site, I would read that as "okay, I can safely do a couple hundred". If I saw a "100 request limit", I would read that as "okay, long as I don't go above about 50, it's definitely cool". These things aren't mechanical, and they definitely don't have bots throttling you at exactly 1000. They have bots throttling anything they see as vaguely suspicious, and the 1000 is a guideline for how not to fall into that category.